# UWP StoreContext provides inaccurate information in RELEASE version

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-store-apps

I have an app, published in Windows Store and the app has a trial version. But recently the trial version provides the full version somehow.

When I debugged the code, it shows that the following piece of code gets called twice in the release version and once it says that Trial is true and secondly it says Trial is false.

```
if (storeContext == null)
            {
                storeContext = StoreContext.GetDefault();
            }
            appLicense = await storeContext.GetAppLicenseAsync();

            if (appLicense.IsActive)
            {
                if (appLicense.IsTrial)
                {
                    isTrial = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    isTrial = false;
                }
            }
```

When I debug the code in Release version it `appLicense.IsTrial` gets evaluated two times and that's how it produces two different results. Is it a bug? Should I tell Microsoft about this? Or is it just related to me somehow? If you try my app from store [here](https://www.microsoft.com/store/apps/9NV62DV88V0N) you can probably see that it provides full access to the application and that the search is available to use while it's disabled in Trial version. Please help me with this.

**Update:**
The ExtendedSplash code:

```
public sealed partial class ExtendedSplash : Page
{
    internal Rect splashImageRect; // Rect to store splash screen image coordinates.
    private SplashScreen splash; // Variable to hold the splash screen object.
    internal bool dismissed = false; // Variable to track splash screen dismissal status.
    internal Frame rootFrame;

    // Define methods and constructor

    public ExtendedSplash(SplashScreen splashscreen, bool loadState)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Listen for window resize events to reposition the extended splash screen image accordingly.
        // This ensures that the extended splash screen formats properly in response to window resizing.
        Window.Current.SizeChanged += new WindowSizeChangedEventHandler(ExtendedSplash_OnResize);

        splash = splashscreen;
        if (splash != null)
        {
            // Register an event handler to be executed when the splash screen has been dismissed.
            splash.Dismissed += new TypedEventHandler<SplashScreen, Object>(DismissedEventHandler);

            // Retrieve the window coordinates of the splash screen image.
            splashImageRect = splash.ImageLocation;
            //PositionImage();

            // If applicable, include a method for positioning a progress control.
            //PositionRing();
        }

        // Create a Frame to act as the navigation context
        rootFrame = new Frame();
    }

    void PositionImage()
    {
        //extendedSplashImage.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, splashImageRect.X);
        //extendedSplashImage.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, splashImageRect.Y);
        //extendedSplashImage.Height = splashImageRect.Height;
        //extendedSplashImage.Width = splashImageRect.Width;
    }

    void PositionRing()
    {
        splashProgressRing.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, splashImageRect.X);// + (splashImageRect.Width * 0.5) - (splashProgressRing.Width * 0.5));
        splashProgressRing.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, (splashImageRect.Y + splashImageRect.Height));// + splashImageRect.Height * 0.1));
    }

    // Include code to be executed when the system has transitioned from the splash screen to the extended splash screen (application's first view).
    async void DismissedEventHandler(SplashScreen sender, object e)
    {
        dismissed = true;

        // Complete app setup operations here...

        await TrialManager.IsTrialLicense();
        // this is the code that gets called to see the Trial / Purchase

        DismissExtendedSplash();
    }

    async void DismissExtendedSplash()
    {
        await Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, 
            () => 
            {
                // Navigate to mainpage
                rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(IndexPage));
                // Place the frame in the current Window
                Window.Current.Content = rootFrame;
            });
    }

    void ExtendedSplash_OnResize(Object sender, WindowSizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Safely update the extended splash screen image coordinates. This function will be executed when a user resizes the window.
        if (splash != null)
        {
            // Update the coordinates of the splash screen image.
            splashImageRect = splash.ImageLocation;
            //PositionImage();

            // If applicable, include a method for positioning a progress control.
            //PositionRing();
        }
    }

    void RestoreStateAsync(bool loadState)
    {
        if (loadState)
        {
            // code to load your app's state here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How/when are you calling this?

Comment: I call this at the app start in an extended splash screen. I have asked Microsoft for support.

Comment: Can you provide more details on when/how you call this from your splash screen